# How to create ActiveX Control in Visual Studio 2010/2015 VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2010, activexobject

I want to create activeX objects (.OCX files) using VB.net visual studio 2010 or 2015.
Is there any way to create activex objects using these tools.
In my project i have software like graphics builder it will accept activex objects, by registering it.
So i want to create some new customized activex objects.

Comment: Any Winforms control can also be an ActiveX control by simply making it [ComVisible(true)].  The usual choice is a UserControl.  One tricky detail however, an extra registry key has to be added to get the control to be recognized by most any ActiveX host programming tool.  [More here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2fe50909-f7f8-4500-a99c-34de2ef567f6/activex-control-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Thank you ....But by making ComVisible True....where can i get .ocx file of that winforms control??
Can you please elaborate more ....i am bit starter.

Comment: Find the DLL back in your project's bin\Release directory.  The filename extension does not matter.  This is not a "starter" kind of project btw, ask for help from your team members.

Comment: **Thank You Sir**
But how can i register that dll file in my software.
My software only accepting .ocx file format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net Cannot create pure ActiveX controls.You can create a .NET DLL with a COM callable wrapper, which is actually a .DLL, using the COM Class.

If you don't need to call the component from a COM  then  create a standard .NET DLL.